thispagestyle does not respect geometry like pagestyle, how to revert to the fancy style on automatic page breaks?
I have defined two page styles like this:
\fancypagestyle{assignmentstart}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \restoregeometry
    \newgeometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1cm,includeheadfoot,headheight=60pt,headsep=20pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{%
        \hrule\\[15pt]\textbf{\large\@assignmentname}\\[2pt]\@author~--~\@rollno,~\@batch\rule[-15pt]{0pt}{2ex}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
    \restoregeometry
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\@author}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\@assignmentname}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\@rollno}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

and then I write \thispagestyle{assignmentstart} before a particular page but that makes my footer disappear, so I have to use \pagestyle{assignmentstart} instead, but the problem with that is if I have too much content on this page there will be an automatic page break which will cause the next page to also have the assignmentstart page style instead of what I want it to be, the fancy style. How can I ensure only the first page gets the assignmentstart style and further pages are of fancy style?
Similar to this question but there are no complete answers there.

At first I thought \fancypagestyle{fancy} would create an infinitle loop, but it seems that \def\ps@fancy{\ps@f@nch@fancyproto} so only \fancypagestyle{f@nch@fancyproto} will create an infinite loop.

@JohnKormylo In older fancyhdr versions \fancypagestyle{fancy} would create an infinite loop, but since version 4.0 (2021) it no longer does.

As the code executed with \thispagestyle is evaluated inside a group (locally), the assignments done by the geometry package don't subsist when the group ends. You can try to make them global with \globaldef=1.
But you also have to restore the geometry manually for the next page, since \thispagestyle doesn't handle it. Try something like:
\AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
  \globaldefs=1
  \restoregeometry
  \globaldefs=0
}

This should work (but not tested), while assignmentstart is not used for multiple pages:
fancypagestyle{assignmentstart}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \globaldefs=1
    \restoregeometry
    \newgeometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1cm,includeheadfoot,headheight=60pt,headsep=20pt}
    \globaldefs=0
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
      \globaldefs=1
      \restoregeometry
      \globaldefs=0
    }
    \fancyhead[C]{%
        \hrule\\[15pt]\textbf{\large\@assignmentname}\\[2pt]\@author~--~\@rollno,~\@batch\rule[-15pt]{0pt}{2ex}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
    \restoregeometry
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\@author}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\@assignmentname}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\@rollno}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}


EDIT: This answer will maybe not always provide the desired output, as the code in \thispagestyleis executed at the page shipout routine. See also the question Fancyhdr geometry correct with pagestyle but not thispagestyle.

Wow! This does exactly what I want if I also add \pagestyle{fancy} in the hook. Thank you.

@SujalSingh It seems that this solution sometimes doesn't work, as \thispagestyle is executed in the shipout routine. See also this question.
